# Sony SEL 18-200mm very blurry at the right part of the photo

Tags: image-quality, sony-alpha

I own a Sony a6000 and recently upgraded the kit lens (10-50) for an 18-200mm lens. The problem I face is that at the right part of the photos, mostly on wide angle, the photo is very blurry compared to the left part. I attached some photos so that you can see for yourselves. I did even clean the lens and the sensor. I have to say that the kit lens doesn't produce the same blur even though it is a bit blurry also. Is it something from the lens or from the camera sensor? Any help is appreciated

[image][image][image]

Later edit: Here are some comparison photos. First one is with the kit lens, second with the zoom lens. You can clearly see the right part of the photo is messed up.[image][image]

Both of them taken at f 5.6, 32mm ,ISO 100. BTW reviews say that f5.6 is recommended at 18-50 mm on the zoom lens.

Meanwhile I got my hands on a brand new zoom lens same type as mine and look at the difference. The right part is much much better in terms of blur. Same settings.

[image]

So hopefully they let me keep this one.

Comment: The left and right sides of the images show objects that are at different distances. Do you have this problem with images that show objects on both sides of the frame that are the same distance away?

Comment: @xiota In the third image you can see the bushes on the right are blurry where the flowers in the center of the image at the same distance are more sharp.

Comment: More like the bottom right corner. On the top picture, the antenna mast at top is reasonably sharp, while people under it at the bottom are already blurry. Likely a lens problem. Get a news paper, tape it on a wall, and take pictures to remove all other possible sources if blurriness. If the lens is stabilized, try with stabilization on and off. If problem remains visible send the lenses to service, with the pictures.

Comment: Could you post some pictures of a brick wall (or newspaper, as xenoid suggests) taken head on, along with settings (focal length, shutter speed, aperture, ISO)?  It would also be helpful to have comparison images from your old lens with the same settings.  Use a tripod.

Comment: Would also help to have more detail about lenses so the exact model can be identified.

Comment: @xenoid Sounds like a good answer... =)

Comment: Normally I'd chock it up to the fact that it's a super zoom and hey, the lens design had to sacrifice somewhere. But that lower right corner just looks exceptionally bad. If it's a recent purchase, send that sucker back and try a different copy / get it warrantied and repaired.

Comment: Don't put too much stock in the difference between the last two photos. They seem to have been made at different focal lengths and focus distances. It probably is a misaligned lens, but comparisons between one lens and another need to be made as close as possible to the exact same conditions (focal length, aperture, focus distance, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More like the bottom right corner. On the top picture, the antenna mast at top is reasonably sharp, while people under it at the bottom are already blurry.

Likely a lens problem. Get a newspaper, tape it on a wall, and take pictures to remove all other possible sources if blurriness. If the lens is stabilized, try with stabilization on and off.

If problem remains visible send the lens to service, with the pictures.

Comment: Thanks, will come back with a new head on picture. meanwhile this is the lens I am talking about: https://www.imaging-resource.com/lenses/sony/e-18-200mm-f3.5-6.3-oss-le-sel18200le/review/ Should I take it with multiple AF points?

Comment: OK so it has stabilization (so test with and without). Tests show its seems [a bit soft in the corners](https://www.imaging-resource.com/lenses/sony/e-18-200mm-f3.5-6.3-oss-le-sel18200le/review/), though.

Comment: 'A bit' is acceptable, but It seems mine is too soft. I suspect descentered lens but I will do further tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The guys from the shop let me have a new one for tests today and tomorrow. I have attached some other photos, big difference IMO. Let's hope they let me keep it ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

The first photo shows that all four corners are significantly softer than the center, which is not unexpected with an 18-200mm "superzoom" lens when zoomed out to the widest focal length. Compromises in image quality must be made for every lens design. As the flexibility of the lens' intended usage grows, the list of compromises gets longer and the effects of those compromises get more severe. This is often most noticeable at the extremes of the focal length ranges of zoom lenses with a very large focal length range.

As expected, the center is sharper than any of the corners. The upper left and lower right corners of the first image appear to be significantly softer than the upper right and lower left corners.¹ This is usually an indication of *tilt* rather than of a decentered lens element. The tilt may be from one misaligned lens element. It could also be from the entire optical axis of the lens not aligned perpendicular to the camera's sensor. When this occurs with only one lens on a particular camera body, it could mean that the lens' rear flange ring is not square to the lens' optical axis.

<sub>¹ The rest of your test images do not show the left corners of the image with objects at distances that would allow one to compare the performance of the lens at all four corners. It's much more effective to use a flat surface with lots of detail that is parallel to the camera's sensor (and perpendicular to the lens' optical axis) when investigating how a lens performs on the edges and in the corners.</sub>